# Going through a string and see if it contains the second parameter

Tags: python, loops, split, boolean

Hi my question is that i want a function that would have two parameter one being a tweet and another being a hashtag and it will return True if and only if the hashtag is in the tweet and false otherwise.

Examples:

`contains_hashtags('I like bats #batman', 'batman')` results in True

`contains_hashtags('I like bats #batman', 'bat')` results in False because its not the same as #batman.

So far I have

```
def contains_hashtags(tweet, hashtag):
tweet.split(" ")
for char in tweet:
    if tweet.startswith(hashtag):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I tried splitting the tweet first then going through each character and see if it startswith the hashtag

Answer (score 2):

`split` returns an array of strings. Strings are **immutable**, means you need to reassign the proccessed value (array), it does not update automatically and replaces the variable.

Check for each word in the splitted array, if it starts with `#` and if it contains the `hashtag`.

Also, note that `return False` comes only if no hashtag was found, so you can put it **only** after all the cases have been tested and proven wrong:

```
def contains_hashtags(tweet, hashtag):
    tweet = tweet.split() # ' ' by default
    for word in tweet:
        if word.startswith('#') and hashtag in word:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: After I tried that it says that 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith' so even after changing my tweet = tweet.split() i got that error does it mean i need to change my attribute of tweet.startswith to list(tweet.startswith)?

Comment: @naruto321 check that now

Comment: Ok great thanks a lot just wondering so whenever i use startwith() the if statement have to be the for **** in tweet?

Comment: Because i learned that usually its like for word in string if string = 0 return False

Comment: `tweet` is an **array of strings**. you need to check `for word in tweet` to iterate all the strings in it.